# Convex hull in 3D — two colorings for some of the faces

Tags: plotting, color

I'm new to Mathematica :(

I need render 3D graphics of a convex hull of 100 points, but with two colorings.

Image (a) is the convex hull $Q$ of 100 points, and (b) is $Q$ along with the shadow boundary marked.

[image: hull]

Comment: Please post your $100$ points so we can help you.

Comment: We also need to know how point $p$ is chosen or defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
rc = RandomReal[1, {100, 3}];
chm = ConvexHullMesh[rc];
mcc2 = MeshCellCount[chm, 2];
mcc1 = MeshCellCount[chm, 1];
chm1 = ConvexHullMesh[rc, 
  MeshCellStyle -> Join[Thread[Thread[{1, Range[mcc1]}] -> 
      Table[Directive[Thick, RandomColor[]], mcc1]], {2 ->  Opacity[.5]}]]
```

[image]

```
chm2 = ConvexHullMesh[rc, 
  MeshCellStyle -> Join[Thread[Thread[{2, Range[mcc2]}] -> 
   Table[Directive[RandomColor[], EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], FaceForm[Opacity@.7]], mcc2]]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
ConvexHullMesh[Table[RandomReal[], {100}, {3}],
 MeshCellHighlight -> {{2, {4, 5, 6, 10}} -> Red}]
```

[image]